# Action Microsoft.crm.setup.shared.analyzerbase+collectaction failed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2013

I tried to install the [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Report Authoring Extension (with SQL Server Data Tools support)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40343) after I successfully installed the [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) but an error came out saying I didn´t have the requisites, which was Visual Studio 2010.... and I have 2012... so, I downloaded the [2015 version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45013), and once I tried to install it, after the updates and some downloads the setup does, the error: **Action Microsoft.crm.setup.shared.analyzerbase+collectaction failed** appeared and it wouldn't  let me go any further.

I found this article but is not exactly the same error:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2988630
And it lead me to delete some register files.... which is not always the best practice. If I could find something better.

I'm running Windows 8.1.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok..... I found the solution, as it is documented in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2988630):

I took a chance and deleted the specified registry.

"Expand the Windows Registry tree to the following registry directory:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\0EF1E6B4EFCDA2649B26A424D56DAACD**"

The installation ran smoothly afterwards. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I got encountered this error while uninstall the MSCRM and I searched a lot but anything not helped.

At last I got resolved this issue when stopped the **Microsof CRM  Asynchronous Service** from **service.msc**

[image]